# PayPal PHP SDK - payment creation doesn't work on production - empty response

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm just facing that problem for hours. This complete app works locally (OSX/MAMP/modphp/PHP 5.5.18) but for some reason on the production server the payment creation fails: White/Empty response. No Exception, no max_execution time limit reached also HTTP 200. PHP and Apache logs are just fine and also there are no errors on the screen.

Everything before `$payment->create($this->apiContext);` gets executed - after that line the result is blank page.

The production server runs Ubuntu 14.04 / Apache 2.4.7 / modphp / PHP 5.5.9

Here is the code:

```
public function create($data)
{
    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    $total    = 0.0;
    $shipping = 0.0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $item = new Item();
        $item->setName($value->name)
            ->setDescription($value->type)
            ->setCurrency(Option::get('general-settings', 'currency'))
            ->setQuantity($value->amount)
            ->setPrice($value->price);

        $items[] = $item;
        $total += $value->price * $value->amount;
    }

    if ($total < 100) {
        $shipping += 10;
    }

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems($items);

    $details = new Details();
    $details->setShipping($shipping)
    ->setSubtotal($total);

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency(Option::get('general-settings', 'currency'))
        ->setTotal($total+$shipping)
        ->setDetails($details);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("JustinRein Auftag")
        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    $baseUrl = "http://example.ch";
    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/payment?success=true")
        ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/payment?success=false");

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    try {
        $payment->create($this->apiContext);

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        td($ex);
        exit(1);
    }

    return $payment;
}
```

This runs also on paypal sandbox mode. The paypal logfile is also empty.

Comment: This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) is a lot easier to work with and doesn't have problems like this.  It just works.  I'd recommend taking a look if you don't get this resolved soon (and maybe even if you do.)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not official and also I don't to rewrite my code. But if this issue does not get solved, I will have a look, thanks.

Comment: PayPal's own integration reps often prefer and recommend the angelleye library.  Angelleye is an official PayPal Partner, too.  Just something to consider.  You could get payments integrated with it within minutes.

Comment: Blank white page typically means PHP error but errors are not being displayed.  Did you check the PHP error log?  Can you enable error reporting on the server or the script specifically?  An empty response could mean that cURL simply isn't enabled on the server.  Have you checked that?

Comment: Just solved the issue. It was an with "@" suppressed error from a third party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting here to close out the question.  Question author investigated and found a third party library that he was using which was suppressing the error that he needed to see with a '@' operator.  After removing the '@' operator (temporarily?) he was able to correct the problem with the PayPal SDK that he was using.

Comment: oh - so sorry - forget that question here. thanks for that closing answer!
The Paypal SDK had no error - it was just the library that caused the error and than screwed up the paypal payment - so i thought it was the PP SDK.. but it was fine.